# Google SSO Logout Bluemix

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I am using Bluemix Single Sign On service with Google. The authentication works perfectly but I cannot log out using `req.logout()`. I am using ExpressJS.

I have this in my app.js:

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
     req.logout();
     res.redirect('https://' + issuer_id + '/idaas/mtfim/sps/idaas/logout');
});
```

I have also tried req.session.destroy().

My repo is hosted on https://hub.jazz.net/project/sssaini/sso-sssaini-1

Answer (score 0):

Information on configuring the logout can be found at the following link.

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/customizing_apps.html#customizing_apps

It is also necessary sometime to force the cache to clear by adding the header Cache-Control = "no-cache",  to the logout page,